# Employee model details not showing in navbar in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have an issue showing my Employee name and picture in navbar.html

I have a CustomUser model from accounts app structure as below

```
core
  |_accounts
     |_models.py (CustomUser is in here)
  |
  |_employees
    |_models.py (Employee model in here)
```

My CustomUser is as below

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email       = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and my employee model is

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    # PERSONAL DATA
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employees")
    title       = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=10, default='Mr', choices=TITLE, blank=False, null=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(_('Profile Image'), upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True, help_text='upload image < 2.0MB')#work on path username-date/image
    firstname   = models.CharField(_('Firstname'), max_length=125, null=False, blank=False)
    lastname    = models.CharField(_('Lastname'), max_length=125, null=False, blank=False)
```

In my navbar template I have

```
<img alt="image" src="{{ request.user.employees.image.url }}" class="user-img-radious-style">
```

and

```
<div class="dropdown-title">Hello {{ request.user.firstname }}</div>
```

My template is not showing the desired results

Comment: It should be `{{ request.user.employees.firstname }}` & for image part check your media configuration

Comment: There could be multiple Employees related to each CustomUser, is this intended? You'll need to loop through them or select one to show the image for

Comment: @IainShelvington Each Employee is linked to one user

Comment: @AnkitTiwari still not showing for the name and image

Comment: @UmarMilanziSnr why is the Employee.user field a ForeignKey then and why is the related_name "employees" which suggests multiple? Change it to a OneToOneField if there should only be one

Comment: @IainShelvington I made the changes, still not getting firstname showing

Comment: @FaisalNazik this is for the navbar.html, it doesn't have a view link to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your user field should be related to the `CustomUser`, not the `User` class.
In addition, `request.user` will give you an instance of your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in settings.py, which in your case is an instance of the `CustomUser` model, which instance does not have a `firstname` fields.

`AbstractBaseUser` does not come with a `first_name`, `last_name` fields, instead, you can switch your inheritance to an `AbstractUser` and then your `CustomUser` class would automatically inherit `first_name` and `last_name`.

Or as @Ankit suggested you can get the `Employee` first name by doing `request.user.employee.firstname`

Keep in mind, that your relationship should be OneToOne as @Iain suggested.